# How to print a TimeField - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: django, format, typeerror, timefield

This is my model:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
start_time = models.TimeField(null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (str(self.start_time))
```

When I do `Meeting.objects.all()`

I get

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Hopefully this is an easy question!
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TimeField stores time in a python datetime instance. From the django docs:

> **`class TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, **options)`**
>
> A time, represented in Python by a datetime.time instance.

You should be able to print the datetime object directly to the console, but if you need to convert it to a string, you should always use python's built in `time` framework. Specifically, `strftime()`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime